# Android onfling prob

Tags: android, gesture, ontouchlistener, onfling

I want to add a fling action on a LinearLayout. I have used the following code for this purpose.

```
public class NewsActivity extends Activity {

    ..........
    ...........
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       .....................
       .....................
       .....................

       LinearLayout newDeailsBlock = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newdeailsblock);
       // Gesture detection
       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
       gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        newDeailsBlock.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                Log.d("move","Swipe test");
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {                
                    Log.d("move","Left Swipe");
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("move","Right Swipe");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

But it is not working at all amd `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` is returning false. What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try having your Activity extend the below abstract class instead, and then implement the abstract methods `next()` and `previous()` with the functionality you want for the fling.

```
public abstract class SwipeActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector( new SwipeDetector() );
    }

    private class SwipeDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {       
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            // Check movement along the Y-axis. If it exceeds SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH, then dismiss the swipe.
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            // Swipe from right to left.
            // The swipe needs to exceed a certain distance (SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) and a certain velocity (SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY).
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                next();
                return true;
            }

            // Swipe from left to right.
            // The swipe needs to exceed a certain distance (SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) and a certain velocity (SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY).
            if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                previous();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //TouchEvent dispatcher.
        if (gestureDetector != null) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
                //If the gestureDetector handles the event, a swipe has been executed and no more needs to be done.
                return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    protected abstract void previous();
    protected abstract void next();
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks!!!! I want to detect Fling on screen no matter what views on the window but do not affect the views. I have tried lots of example. Some cannot detect the Fling, and some can detect but make the views not touchable. I finally realize the key is the `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`!!!